# Timestamp with timezone from frontend to postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I am sending query to save `created_at` from front end as follows:

```
new Date().toISOString();
```

On the server, I am saving `created_at` coming in the request without modification using knex:

```
knex('table').insert({created_at: created_at});
```

On the server, the `date +"%Z %z"` shows `UTC +0000`.

In postgresql table, the `created_at` column is of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`.
The `SHOW TIMEZONE;` command in postgresql db on server shows `Etc/UTC`.

To get daily details, from front end, I send `.toISOString()` of the start of day and end of day of `new Date()` for current date and then subtract/add day to these values to get details of different dates. It shows correct data.

The problem I am facing is getting aggregated daily data (`count` of `created_at` based on client timezone). I am sending query to backend without any params and getting data from backend with the following query:

```
knex('table')
  .select(db.raw('DATE(created_at) as date, COUNT(*) as count'))
  .groupBy('date')
  .orderBy('date', 'desc');
```

then setting the response in frontend as follows:

```
response?.data.data.map((d) => ({ date: d.date, count: d.count }));
```

The `count` data that I am getting are incorrect. How can I solve the issue? Thanks.

Edit:

Examples of `created_at` when saving and getting the latest one:

Logs when saving a created_at:

- in front end:

```
const now = new Date();
now.toString()  Tue Feb 15 2022 21:48:57 GMT+1300
now.ISOString()  2022-02-15T08:48:57.875Z // this is sent to server to save created_at
```

- in backend server:

```
created_at in request  2022-02-15T08:48:57.875Z
const createdAtDateObj = new Date(created_at);
createdAtDateObj.toString()  Tue Feb 15 2022 08:48:57 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
createdAtDateObj.toISOString()  2022-02-15T08:48:57.875Z
```

- created_at saved in postgres:

```
2022-02-15 08:48:57.875+00
```

Logs when getting the latest created_at:

- in backend server:

```
createdAtDateObj.toString()  Tue Feb 15 2022 08:48:57 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
createdAtDateObj.toISOString()  2022-02-15T08:48:57.875Z
```

- in frontend:

```
const createdAtDateObj = new Date(created_at);
createdAtDateObj.toString()  Tue Feb 15 2022 21:48:57 GMT+1300
createdAtDateObj.toISOString()  2022-02-15T08:48:57.875Z
```

The count numbers are wrong since I think they are aggregated based on timestamp in UTC timezone that are being saved.

Edit 2:
I tried sending the following from client to server instead of `new Date().toISOString();` to be able to set the offset in the db.

```
const postgresTimestampTz = format(now, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXX');
```

So, the server logs `created_at` as `2022-02-19 14:13:44.738+1300` for example in the incoming request, but seems like it saves the date in the database in UTC (for example: `2022-02-19 01:13:44.738+00`) ignoring the offset.

Comment: i faced a similar issue with timezones in pg, apparently for me there was no need for the `timestamp with timezone` type, just store your values in a timestamp without timezone, and frontends will handle localizing the clocks from the browser, is the data error range within your timezone difference?

Comment: @M-Raw, `timestamp with timezone` is the data type you want to store timestamps as.  Otherwise you will get timestamps that are not rooted to `UTC` and will be all over the place depending on what created them and what is displaying them. The solution is going to be found by determining what is actually going? Add to question 1) Example of actual timestamp data stored in database 2) What `new Date().toISOString();` returns for that data? 3) What are the `count` numbers and why do you think they are incorrect?

Comment: Thanks to both of you. @AdrianKlaver I have updated my question as you suggested.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  the timezone type docs says it is there for legacy reasons and it is not recommended for usage, the general information on the web is what you mentioned, but storing the timezone always caused me issues https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: @M-Raw re-read the docs, it is says, "...We do not recommend using the type time with time zone (though it is supported by PostgreSQL for legacy applications and for compliance with the SQL standard). ..." So the issue is with `time with time zone`, not `timestamp with time zone`. FYI, the timezone is not stored with `timestamp with time zone`. Using that field just rotates the timestamp to `UTC` when storing it.

Comment: You need to define what 'backend server' is? Also I'm not seeing how `2022-02-14T07:57:19.585Z` is ending up as `2022-02-14 19:33:21.079+00` in Postgres? I could see the hour being moved by a timezone, I don't see 57 minutes --> 33 and 19 seconds --> 21. So either you are looking at the wrong timestamp in the database or something else is going in the move from Javascript to the database. I would look at the Postgres logs to see what is actually hitting the database when you do the insert.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver you're right, my understanding of it is because it stored the timezone offset, frontends like angular or nextjs interpreted those offsets one more time and was causing the difference that similarly shows in adam question, it could be that i need more steps to get the time right, across frontend->backend->database and removing the timezone and setting everything to UTC was the solution

Comment: It does not store the offset either. You need to go through this [Datetime](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) a couple of more times, in particular '8.5.1.3. Time Stamps'. The offset you see comes from Postgres formatting the datetime text  according to the rules in the section just mentioned.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I apologize for posting the wrong date. I was in stress. Edited with correct data and you can see the data in server and db are consistent. The backend server is a node express api hosted on a remote server. But I will go through the docs you mentioned and I think your last comment about not storing the offset is the issue. Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem `Tue Feb 15 2022 21:48:57 GMT+1300` = `2022-02-15T08:48:57.875Z`.  And it is being stored correctly in Postgres. The issue must in the query you are using to do the aggregation. I suspect it is what is being defined as a day, whether that is Midnight -> Midnight local time or UTC. Adding the query to the question would help.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the query to get the aggregated data is already in the question. `knex('table').select(db.raw('DATE(created_at) as date, COUNT(*) as count')).groupBy('date').orderBy('date', 'desc');`

Comment: Hmm, missed that. That query is going to group by dates in `UTC` which is not going to be the same as a date in local time. You still have not said what timezone you want the date count to be in?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Need to the count by date in client timezone. Also added some further efforts in the question.

Comment: Per my previous comment you need to read [DateTime](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) section '8.5.1.3. Time Stamps'. Offsets are not stored, the incoming is rotated to and stored as `UTC` using either the supplied offset/timezone or the server `TimeZone`(in your case UTC). On retrieval it is displayed in the server `TimeZone`(in your case UTC). If you want to use the timestamps as local time you will to convert them from UTC to local time.